# Add empty value to AssociationField in EasyAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, easyadmin

I want my `AssociationField` to display a blank value by defaut, in ordre to force the users to select an item.

As I understand, `AssociationField` is based on `EntityType` FormType.

My Problem is, if the field of my entity is required, the create form renders the AssociationField without empty value, and thus selects the first value.

I haven't seen any option to add a placeholder to a select for required properties.

Here are some samples:

My Doctrine entity :

```php
//Player.php
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'players')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name:'team_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', nullable: false)]
private Team $team;
```

... and my CrudController

```php
//PlayerCrudController.php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        //...
        AssociationField::new('team'),
        //...
    ]
}
```

And the create form displays a select with already a value selected.

I've looked into the docs but couldn't find how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Try `->setRequired(false)`, works for me with EasyAdmin 4.6.1.